# VS 2017 is telling me I am trying to convert variables but I am not

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to set up a function that takes a few arrays to build a deck of cards from a private section in a class. The function is still in the same class but it is in the public section. However Visual Studio debugger is telling me that there is no suitable function to convert string to char. I do not have any char variables in my code nor am i trying to convert it. Both arrays are strings.

It was originally a 2d array going into a 1d array but I changed that to 2 separate arrays to see if that worked but its still telling me I am trying to convert.

```
class Cards {
private:

string deckcontents[13]{"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","K","Q"};
string cardshape[4]{ "H", "S", "D", "C" };
string deck[52]{};

public:

int generaterandcardnum() {
    int num1 = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        num1 = rand() % 10;
    }
    return num1;
}

int generaterandcardsuit() {
    int num2 = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        num2 = rand() % 10;
    }
    return num2;
}

void builddeck(string cards)
{
    int cardnum = generaterandcardnum();
    int cardsuit = generaterandcardsuit();
    string card = deckcontents[cardnum] + cardshape[cardsuit];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++) {
                        //This is where the problem lies
            cards[j] = card;

                        //.cpp(58): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'

            j = j + 1;
        }

    }
    return;
}
};
```

Comment: This is not the debugger telling you anything, it's the compiler refusing to compile your code; rightfully so. How exactly do you expect this to work? `cards` is a string. `cards[j]` is the *j*-th character in that string. `card` is a string. You cannot assign an entire string to a single character of another string…

Comment: Listen to what your compiler is telling you `"cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'"` ... seems really clear why the compiler is complaining... See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: David I understand what you mean but when it comes to trying to see the issue through my perspective I was confused as to why it was telling me that for I had no intentions on converting.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a char in the string with `cards[j]` because `cards` is a string.

To access a specific card in the array, you need to change your function's signature:

```
void builddeck(string cards[])
```

Comment: Lol thank you I realized that after I posted. Just checked today and It all went well.